# How to count number times a given number appears in binary tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

Could someone please let me know why my code isn't working? I am trying to count the number of times a given value appears in a binary tree using recursion. However, this approach is not working. I'd really appreciate some feedback and insight. Thank you.

```
public int valCount(int val) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return valCount(val, *root);
}

public int valCount(int val, Node *root) {
  int cnt = 0;
  if (root->left != null) {
    if (root->data == val) {
        cnt++;
    }
    int leftValCount = valCount(val, root->left);
  }
  if (root->right != null) {
    if (root->data == val) {
        cnt++;
    }
    int rightValCount = valCount(val, root->right);
  }
  return cnt + leftValCount + rightValCount;
}
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Is this really C++? `public int`and `null` aren't part of standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake in recursion is to worry about stack frames other than the current one. Let the recursion do that work for you. Following this rule-of-thumb makes the code much easier to reason about.

The algorithm is simple: for each node, return 1 if the current node matches the target value else 0 if it doesn't and add the results of calling the same function on the left and right subtrees. The base case is when the function is called with a null root, return 0.

```
int valCount(int val, Node *root) {
    if (!root) return 0;

    return (root->val == val ? 1 : 0) + 
           valCount(val, root->left) + 
           valCount(val, root->right);
}
```